# Android Studio - View error

Tags: java, android

In Android Studio, I try to show a class view, but it shows me error.

GameActivity.java

```
private GameView view;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    view = new GameView(this);
    setContentView(view);
}
```

GameView.java

```
import android.content.Context;

public class GameView {
    public GameView(Context context) {

    }
}
```

The error is on setContentView -> "cannot resolve method ..."

I use JDK 8 Update 25

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GameView needs to inherit from View in order for arguments to setContentView to be a View. "cannot resolve method" is saying "the method including the argument types" (cannot be found).

In other words, your compiler is saying setContentView(GameView) is not a method, which is true.

Comment: Thanks, but how to fix it?

Comment: Extend GameView from View so that GameView is a View.